# Sharing Access Token Between Clients

Tags: identityserver4

I have an application that authenticates with Identity Server 4  using implicit flow.  The application is separated into two separate .net core applications.  One application handles the back end and the other handles serving the front end.

The back end and front end share the same scopes, api name, and authority settings.

I will be writing an integration with a 3rd party.  Our back end application will call into the 3rd party application.  We need to ensure that calls to the 3rd party application are authenticated.  I'd like to share the access token the back end application receives from the front end and send that to the 3rd party application.  I am not quite sure of the setup required to do this.

I thought that I could add a new Client to Identity Server and set it up with only the needed scopes required by the 3rd party.  But in my local testing, I haven't been able to get this to work.  I get an error IDX10804 Unable to obtain configuration from .../.well-known/openid-configuration - A security error occurred.

My config looks like:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "thirdPartyClient",
                ClientName = "thirdPartyClient",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
                },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = false
            },

            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "myapplication",
                ClientName = "myapplication",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },


                RedirectUris = { "https://.../callback.html" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://.../index.html"
                AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://..." },
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
                    "myscope",
                },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = false
            }
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: what's the status?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added redirect uri for the client `thirdPartyClient`. Without redirect uri client won't be valid.

> RedirectUris
>
> Specifies the allowed URIs to return tokens or authorization codes to

If you turn on [detailed logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx)  with Disable Just My code. You could see the error logs to find the actual reason

Comment: I'll try the detailed logging.  For the thirdPartyClient, the call flow is :  

1. User does some action in the browser 

2. browser calls our C# Web API 

3. Our C# Web API calls thirdPartyClient

4. thirdPartyClient does an action and returns HTTP response
5. C# Web API receives response and returns result to user's browser

In this flow the user doesn't leave our UI.  Is a redirect URI needed in this case?

But eventually, We will need to add a flow where a user clicks a link and the link performs SSO and logs the user into the 3rd party UI.

Comment: @RiazAhmad what i mean is `RedirectUris = { "https://.../callback.html" },` part is missing for the `ClientId = "thirdPartyClient",` have you try to add that?

Comment: I fixed the IDX10804 error.  It was a simple invalid configuration of authority url,  runs on http locally.

With that resolved, I get an "audience is invalid" error.  So it looks like I cannot reuse the same access token because the clientid is different.  The error goes away if I use ClientId = "myapplication" instead of ClientId = "thirdPartyClient".  Which does make since because the token is signed.  How is this supposed to work in a microservice architecture? Does every service need to use the same client id?  How do we perform SSO if the initial login was from a different client id?

Comment: No you may use different client_id, but you must add every required details